# Print Indian rupee symbol (₹)

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, thermal-printer

I am using an OVIO Bluetooth thermal printer. I want to print the Indian Rupee symbol (**₹**). When i append the symbol to string and send the string to be printed, everything is printed fine other than the symbol. A "**?**" symbol is printed instead of "**₹**". I have set charset encoding to `UTF-8`.

You can find the printer manual from [THIS LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f1rLebJH3tmsV-9jALLRUs5kyIXZFRGC/view?usp=sharing). In the manual, on **Page 11**, there is an option to define user-defined character but don't know how that can be achieved.

`String msg="₹"+"1,000.00";
 outputStream.write(msg.getBytes("UTF-8"))`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [unicode character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/index.htm). In Java it's used like

`String msg = Html.fromHtml("\u20B9 1,000.00")`